# How to reset a form after component leave in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on reactive-forms in angular 7.I have 3 components and each component has a form.based on if,components switches.I'm not using routes ,just hiding and showing components.if we reach back to previous component.then angular-material input have a red border.How to remove that border

dashboard.component.ts(parent)

```
<section>
  <mat-card class="auth-card">

    <mat-card-content>
      <div [ngStyle]="componentConst.showAcc ? {'display':'block'} : {'display':'none'}" id="acc ">
        <app-account (showStep)="onNextStepShow($event)"></app-account>
      </div>
      <div [ngStyle]="componentConst.showC ? {'display':'block'} : {'display':'none'}" id="cred ">
        <app-cred (showNextStep)="onNext($event)" (showStip)="onShowPrev()"></app-cred>
      </div>
```

appaccount.ts

```
    <form [formGroup]="providerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-control">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input  type="text" placeholder="Provider" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            formControlName="providerName">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let providerItem of providersData" [value]="providerItem.providerName">
              {{providerItem.providerName}}</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngIf="providersData.length===0  && isSearching!='false'" disabled>Begin typing to search...
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
          <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControl.providerName.errors">
            <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.providerName.errors.required"> * Provider is required</mat-error>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="button-section">
        <button mat-button [disabled]="!isSelected">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Switching time you should reset a form. so in that time reset but form field are touch then you will get a red border because of the validation. add this code in the switching between between form event.

```
this.providerForm.reset()
providerForm.markAsPristine();
providerForm.markAsUntouched();
```